# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow loops

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a question about SharePoint Designer Loops. If I create a `Today` variable using a workflow variable will the `Today` variable update inside the loop or will it remain the same date that the workflow was saved?

Comment: Are you setting `Today` within the loop?

Comment: @wjervis haven't setup the loop yet. I'm just curious if the `Today` will update inside of a loop. If not I will need to find another way to approach my issue.

Comment: If you're setting it in the loop, it should update.  If you're setting it once, outside the loop, it will not update.

Comment: @wjervis I'm going to let a workflow I've setup run it's course over night. If you could, can you submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `Today` within the loop, it should update.  If you're setting it prior to the loop, and checking within the loop, it will not update.